# Serverless Lambda in Ca-central-1 region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm trying to set-up serverless framework for Lambda function in AWS (CA-Central-1 Region) and while trying to create the CloudFormation I'm having issues with the ReporterFunction since it's not reachable from my region

[image]

Do you have any ideas how can I fix this issue and import the Reporter function?

Much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution : You don't have to switch the region while creating the cloudformation stack, just specify the region while deploying the application using : sls deploy --region ca-central-1.